# How to get scripts output and process in another script in PHP using ob_start?

Tags: php, http, output, ob-start

OK look:

What I want to do is the following (this is an example):

1. $output = require( "script_execution.php" );
2. echo str_replace( "hello", "bye", $output );

The solution I have:

(script_execution.php)

```
<?php
   echo "hello world....";
?>
```

(solution.php)

```
<?php

  ob_start();
  require( "script_execution.php" );
  $output = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  echo $output; // WOW!!! but.......................

?>
```

(output)

**bye world....**

Here is the problem: That solution works fine but, ¿What happens if "script_execution.php" has an (exit;) ??? 
The final output will be wrong because before the third instruction all execution running is stopped.

¿What can I do to get the final output of "script_execution.php" without exit my script (solution.php)? Because as you know, the final output of script_execution.php (independent of the exit; instruction) is:

**hello world....**

Thanks! (maybe using threads??)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you evaluate the script with `include` or `require`, and it calls `exit()`, your script will terminate.

You have two options that I see:

1. Using a shutdown handler with [`register_shutdown_function()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) to run when `exit()` is called, then capture the output buffer within the function and print it.
2. Execute only `script_execution.php` by making an HTTP request to your server, with something similar to:

   ```
   $output = file_get_contents( 'http://www.yoursite.com/script_execution.php');
   ```

Comment: great! I will use the first for the ob_start.. maybe the second for another use. Thank you!